# ElasticSerch Multi level Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm pushing logs to a index. It will have only the response code. I need to aggregate and get the count based on the response code.

Index Data :

```
 {
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 3,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "server_logs",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "LSi5wm8BFsMbdnOaT1F9",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "system" : "cspkong-poc-chaos1",
          "jmeterData" : [
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:17",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:17",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:17",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:18",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:19",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:19",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:20",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:20",
              "status" : 200
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "server_logs",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Lii5wm8BFsMbdnOaUVEk",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "system" : "cspkong-poc-chaos2",
          "jmeterData" : [
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:21",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:21",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:22",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:22",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:24",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:24",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:25",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:25",
              "status" : 429
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "server_logs",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Mii5wm8BFsMbdnOaVFH9",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "system" : "cspkong-poc-chaos6",
          "jmeterData" : [
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:43",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:43",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:03:52",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:04:01",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:04:10",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:04:18",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:04:21",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:04:23",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:04:30",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:04:30",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:04:37",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:04:37",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:04:43",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:04:51",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:04:56",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:04:59",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:04:59",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:05:08",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:05:15",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:05:15",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:05:24",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:05:27",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:05:28",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:05:31",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:05:31",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:05:35",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:05:35",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:05:41",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:05:47",
              "status" : 429
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:05:47",
              "status" : 200
            },
            {
              "date" : "2020-01-10 13:05:55",
              "status" : 200
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected Response

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "sytemname" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "cspkong-poc-chaos1",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "totalcount" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 200,
                "doc_count" : 4
              },
              {
                "key" : 429,
                "doc_count" : 4
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "cspkong-poc-chaos2",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "totalcount" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 200,
                "doc_count" : 5
              },
              {
                "key" : 429,
                "doc_count" : 3
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "cspkong-poc-chaos6",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "totalcount" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 200,
                "doc_count" : 14
              },
              {
                "key" : 429,
                "doc_count" : 19
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have already written a query to retrieve it. But still i cant able to get the count for each response code.

```
GET server_logs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "sytemname": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "system.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "totalcount": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "jmeterData.status"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Index Settings

```
{
  "server_logs" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "_doc" : {
        "properties" : {
          "jmeterData" : {
            "properties" : {
              "date" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "status" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "system" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone help me out in this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you paste your index mapping, did you set up nested fields explicitly?

Comment: Hi @renqHIT I have added my index mapping. No i haven't declared as nested. Is there a way to achieve this without nested.. ?

Comment: no, you must specify nested fields for aggregation

Answer (score 0):

You must specify mapping for further usage for fields like date and status. Otherwise, logs are not indexed and just plain text.

First, specify your index mapping explicitly

```
"jmeterData" : {
    "type" : "nested",
    "properties" : {
        "status" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "date" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "epoch_millis||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        }
    }
}
```

Then use nested aggregation.

```
GET server_logs/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "jmeterData"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "NAME": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "jmeterData.status",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```